# How to access MongoDB's aggregation framework from the rmongodb R package

Tags: r, mongodb

I'm trying to access the mongodb aggregation framework from rmongodb.  It should be available through mongo.command() but I cannot get the bson correct.

Here is a replicable example.  In R, set up a test collection:

```
mongo <- mongo.create()
db <- "test"
ns <- "test.people"

buf <- mongo.bson.buffer.create()
mongo.bson.buffer.append(buf, "name", "John")
mongo.bson.buffer.append(buf, "age", 22L)
b <- mongo.bson.from.buffer(buf)
mongo.insert(mongo, ns, b);

buf <- mongo.bson.buffer.create()
mongo.bson.buffer.append(buf, "name", "John")
mongo.bson.buffer.append(buf, "age", 35L)
b <- mongo.bson.from.buffer(buf)
mongo.insert(mongo, ns, b);

buf <- mongo.bson.buffer.create()
mongo.bson.buffer.append(buf, "name", "Fred")
mongo.bson.buffer.append(buf, "age", 27L)
b <- mongo.bson.from.buffer(buf)
mongo.insert(mongo, ns, b);

Now, on the mongo console, the following works:

use test
db.runCommand({
  aggregate : "people", pipeline : [
  { $group :
    { _id    : '$name',
      total  : { $sum : 1 } } } ]
})
```

It seems like the following in R would achieve the same effect:

```
mongo.command(mongo, "test", list(
   aggregate="people", 
   pipeline=list(
      group=list(
         "_id"="$name",
         total=list("$sum"=1)
      )
   )
))
```

This does not work.

For this particular aggregation, I am aware that there are other ways to do it.  I'm just providing it as a simple example but I want to get to more complex aggregations in the future.

Also, I am aware of another R package for mongodb that I might be able to look into to do the trick, but I'm pretty heavily invested into using this package right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the following code will give you the result you want:

```
sub.buf <- mongo.bson.buffer.create();
  mongo.bson.buffer.start.object(sub.buf, "$group");
  mongo.bson.buffer.append(sub.buf, "_id", "$name"); 
    mongo.bson.buffer.start.object(sub.buf, "total");
    mongo.bson.buffer.append(sub.buf, "$sum", 1L); 
    mongo.bson.buffer.finish.object(sub.buf);
  mongo.bson.buffer.finish.object(sub.buf);
sb <- mongo.bson.from.buffer(sub.buf);

buf <- mongo.bson.buffer.create();
mongo.bson.buffer.append(buf, "aggregate", "people"); 
  mongo.bson.buffer.start.array(buf, "pipeline");
    mongo.bson.buffer.append(buf, "0", sb);
  mongo.bson.buffer.finish.object(buf);
cmd <- mongo.bson.from.buffer(buf);
```

I found the challenge with performing aggregates in rmongodb to be that the user:

1. is almost required to use bson buffers
2. is required to specify the pipeline argument as an array
3. must label the entries in the pipeline array with integers
    (I believe this necessitates specifying the actual aggregation mechanics as a sub-bson objects)

I could be wrong about (3), though I haven't seen any other examples anywhere on how to perform a "group" aggregate which would discount the statement.

Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks like it will produce aggregation pipeline with stage named `"group"` and there is no such pipeline operator.  The operator is `"$group"` and it's possible that this is the only thing that needs to be corrected.

However, I suspect that using list() with only one "element" creates a subdocument rather than creating an array with one document, which is what a pipeline is supposed to be.  You might try explicitly creating an array with a single element especially if it's the only way to correctly get "$group" in the object.

```
... 
mongo.bson.buffer.start.array(buf, "pipeline") 
mongo.bson.buffer.append(buf, "$group", ... etc 
mongo.bson.buffer.finish.object(buf)
```